# Bash: Checking for string-substring

Tags: string, bash, equality

Following [this answer in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there), I have wrote that function in bash:

```
_add_env()
{
    export $1
    if [[ ":\$$1:" != *":$2:"* ]]; then
            eval $1="\$$1:$2";
    fi
};
```

I'm calling it that way: _merge_env PATH "/home/subway/land"

It seems that the condition is true even though PATH contains the given path.

Here is the relevant bash -x output:

- 579 :[[ :$PATH: != *:/\h\o\m\e/\s\u\b\w\a\y/\l\a\n\d:* ]]
- 580 :eval 'PATH=$PATH:/home/subway/land'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\$$1"` is not evaluated to the content of $PATH, but to `$PATH`. Use variable indirection:

```
[[ ":${!1}:" != *":$2:" ]]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Would you mind to explain what does variable indirection mean? I mean, what exactly is its job?

Comment: Its jobs is what you try here: to use a value of a variable as a name of variable to expand.